# 2 almost Identical selects on same DB table takes vastly different time to execute

Tags: sql, linux, database, postgresql, pentaho-data-integration

for Christmas, I have one question that I realy strugge to find clues about how to deal with..

I have one report DB, it is filled by data from satelite databases, on many smaller machines. Data fetches are executed equally, every 20 min for each satelite DB. They use all same script. They are however on different installations, spread across the country.

Now I have one SELECT, used by pentaho reporting being executed on same DB table in this report DB. and while one SELECT takes miliseconds to be executed, the other takes literally hours. They are being both executed over same table, in same DB running on same Hardware.

*Fast one:*

```
SELECT
 res.ticket_id,
 res.entry_zone,
 res.entry_time,
 res.exit_time,
 res.parking_time,
 res.cost,
 co.org_name,
 cu.firstname,
 cu.surname,
 a.name AS article_name,
 res.car_id 
FROM (SELECT
 lh.ticket_id,
 z.name AS entry_zone,
 lh.park_entered AS entry_time,
 lh.park_leaved AS exit_time,
 interval_to_hourminsec(lh.park_leaved - lh.park_entered) AS parking_time,
 lh.cost,
 lh.article_id,
 sa.contrib_user_id,
 fpl.car_id
 FROM longterm_history lh, zones z, sold_articles sa, flexcore_passing_log fpl
 WHERE lh.park_leaved BETWEEN  '2017-12-18 00:00' AND  '2017-12-19 23:59'
 AND sa.ticket_id = lh.ticket_id
 AND lh.entry_zone = z.zone_number
 AND lh.passlog_id = fpl.id
 AND lh.park_uuid = 100068
 AND z.park_uuid = 100068
 AND sa.park_uuid = 100068
 AND fpl.park_uuid = 100068
 AND lh.entry_zone = 1
) AS res 
LEFT OUTER JOIN articles a ON res.article_id = a.article_id AND a.park_uuid = 100068 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cont_users cu ON res.contrib_user_id = cu.id AND cu.park_uuid = 100068 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cont_orgs co ON cu.org_id = co.id AND co.park_uuid = 100068 
ORDER BY res.exit_time ASC
```

**The slow:**

```
SELECT
 res.ticket_id,
 res.entry_zone,
 res.entry_time,
 res.exit_time,
 res.parking_time,
 res.cost,
 co.org_name,
 cu.firstname,
 cu.surname,
 a.name AS article_name,
 res.car_id 
FROM (SELECT
 lh.ticket_id,
 z.name AS entry_zone,
 lh.park_entered AS entry_time,
 lh.park_leaved AS exit_time,
 interval_to_hourminsec(lh.park_leaved - lh.park_entered) AS parking_time,
 lh.cost,
 lh.article_id,
 sa.contrib_user_id,
 fpl.car_id
 FROM longterm_history lh, zones z, sold_articles sa, flexcore_passing_log fpl
 WHERE lh.park_leaved BETWEEN  '2017-12-18 00:00' AND  '2017-12-19 23:59'
 AND sa.ticket_id = lh.ticket_id
 AND lh.entry_zone = z.zone_number
 AND lh.passlog_id = fpl.id
 AND lh.park_uuid = 100146
 AND z.park_uuid = 100146
 AND sa.park_uuid = 100146
 AND fpl.park_uuid = 100146
 AND lh.entry_zone = 1
) AS res 
LEFT OUTER JOIN articles a ON res.article_id = a.article_id AND a.park_uuid = 100146 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cont_users cu ON res.contrib_user_id = cu.id AND cu.park_uuid = 100146 
LEFT OUTER JOIN cont_orgs co ON cu.org_id = co.id AND co.park_uuid = 100146 
ORDER BY res.exit_time ASC
```

how to find out where is the problem, what causes the second SELECT to be executed hours?

I am using postgres SQL, server version is 9.6.3
Data are fetched into databases by pentaho data-integration

---

Edit:

After running both queries through `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` the biggest significant difference is in this part:

```
                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on longterm_history_park_uuid_idx  (cost=0.00..7609.82 rows=352718 width=0) (actual time=492.753..492.753 rows=354537 loops=1)
                                                 Index Cond: (park_uuid = 100068)
                                                 Buffers: shared read=1238

                                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on longterm_history_park_uuid_idx  (cost=0.00..453.11 rows=20890 width=0) (actual time=4.680..4.680 rows=40021 loops=466475)
                                                 Index Cond: (park_uuid = 100146)
                                                 Buffers: shared hit=65306361 read=139
```

and it seems that whatmakes second SELECT slower is `loops=466475` instead of `loops=1` dne by first SELECT. But I have no idea what it means or how to fix it..

---

Edit2:

I have find tootl to share plans online, here are links:

Fast query: https://explain.depesz.com/s/oYQLB

Slow query: https://explain.depesz.com/s/uOtf

Slow query executed fast, while fetches were off: https://explain.depesz.com/s/4h4F

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please post `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for both queries. It would also be nice if you told us what the difference between the queries is rather than letting us search.

Comment: There is no difference in both queries, the only difference is `park_uuid` value, dates and other parameters are same for both.

I am aware of fact that you don't have much options to help without access to complete data set. I am more like asking for suggestions how to analyze problem..

Comment: Could it be a parameter sniffing issue?

Comment: If the only difference is the value of park_uuid then, as a start, I would run counts of the rows in each table for each of the park_uuids you are searching for.  I would also try the query through the command-line tool psql to eliminate anything that Pentaho might be doing.  Maybe you did that already?  And, I think the query optimizer would deal with this, but I would put the literal value in once and use joins to match it to the other tables, to help the optimiser do its job.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I am affraid results are too big for a post here. Is there any way I can share them with you by other way? I was trying to get info of them by myself, but it seems too messy..might need to get abit used to it.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have found way to share plans online, so added links to initial post..

Comment: Great. And as soon as you examined the plans, you found the correct answer yourself - the table statistics were off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was resolved.

After learning how to read `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` with help of lots web based tools to graphically show it, I have noticed that second (SLOWER) select is doing high number of loops and optimizer expects less rows to be returned than it really returns.

This was sign of wrong data that are optimizers calculation based of. To solve it, I have run `VACUUM ANALYZE` on the whole DB.

Result is significant improvement of performance, query execution time was shortened **from 4265437.080 ms** *to 547.202 ms.*